# (JDK 1.6 and ojdbc6.jar) vs (JDK 1.5 and ojdbc14.jar)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ojdbc

I am facing a strange kind of scenario. I have the following table, with two columns.

```
Customer:

Customer_ID nvarchar2
Subscription_Date Date
```

I am trying to get the column type of Subscription_Date using Meta Data as shown below:

```
ResultSet rs = selectStmt.executeQuery("SELECT Customer_ID, Subscription_Date FROM Cusomter");
java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
int type1 = rsMetaData.getColumnType(2);
```

If I use JDK 1.6 and ojdbc6.jar, `type1` is returned as

```
93 (java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP)
```

If I use JDK 1.5 and ojdbc14.jar, `type1` is returned as

```
91 (java.sql.Types.DATE)
```

But in both the scenarios, the actual column type of Subscription_Date is `DATE`.
Is this some backward compatability issue? Or is my way of coding is wrong?
Can you guys please look into it and provide some suggestion?

Comment: Read the release notes for the driver, this is documented. The new behaviour is correct (because the old driver would "remove" the time part from a `DATE` column)

Comment: So if I wanted to support both ojdbc14 with JDK 1.5 and ojdbc6 with JDK 1.6, how should I proceed...??

Comment: If you need to support JDK 1.5 you should use `ojdbc5.jar` (which would work on Java 6 as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [oracle datatype of `DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847) is identical to the SQL standards (and JDBC) concept of `TIMESTAMP` as it stores date + time. The SQL standards concept of `DATE` only stores a date (so year, month, day in month). The behavior in `ojdbc6.jar` is correct and `ojdbc14.jar` was wrong.

Not all relational database servers use the exact same names for things. The SQL standards did not emerge until after there were relational databases, and some (or most) kept using their legacy naming for datatypes instead of moving to the names of the standards.